# Is there a way to enable pressing/releasing shift to Pan while already rotating, without having to release the middle mouse button?

Tags: 3d-view, shortcut

new to Blender 2.82

Basically just wondering, if I am rotating around my object, is there a way I can press shift while still holding the middle mouse button, and enable it to start panning?

It feels very awkward to have to release the middle mouse button, hold shift, then hold the middle mouse button again, then if I want to go back to rotating I have to release shift and the middle mouse button.

It just feels like there is a way to enable this perhaps, but I could not find it in the preferences

Answer (score 5):

Under *User Preferences > Keymap* navigate to 3D View > 3D View Global.

Look for the operator *Rotate View* and under it expand *View 3D Rotate Modal*.
Add a new entry there with the sub option *Switch to Move*

[image]

You may optionally want to add one to *View 3D Move Modal* too, for equivalent behavior.

Answer (score 2):

This is verified working in Blender 3.0.1 and involves changing the keymap: [image: keymap]

- Go into `Edit` -> `Preferences` -> `Keymap`
- Search for `view3d.rotate` and find the one bound to Mouse / Middle Mouse
- Under View3D Rotate Modal, click `Add New`
- Pick `Switch to Move` from the list
- Expand the tiny ▶ next to `Switch to Move` (if you try and do it on the <kbd>A</kbd> just to the right without expanding, it won't let you pick <kbd>Shift</kbd>)
- Click the <kbd>A</kbd> next to `Switch to Move` and press <kbd>Left Shift</kbd>
- Pick `Press` from the drop-down to its right

Now repeat the process for `view3d.pan`, `Switch to Rotate`, and `Release`